# GPU Image Framework

Tags: ios, ios6, gpu

I am making a application that you can apply different effects to photos using GPU Image Framework by Brad Larson. I would like to create a Thermal Filter, and a x-ray filter. I have not yet found a way to make my own custom filters.

Can someone please give an example of a custom filter and explain what I might have to do to create some image filters like I described above.

Comment: Hi any update on these two effects?